# Regex: Finding para around a word using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I want to find paragraph around a word using regex expressions, start and end of paragraph is identified by delimiter '@@'. I am using alteryx regex tool with tokenize method, its perl 5 compatible.

e.g.
Text:

> @@Consumers can also monitor their accounts regularly by allowing them
> to keep their accounts safe. Around-the-clock access to banking
> information provides early detection of fraudulent activity, thereby
> acting as a guardrail against financial damage or loss.@@ Online Bill
> Payment one of the great advantages of online banking is online bill
> pay. Rather than having to write checks or fill out forms to pay
> bills, once you set up your accounts at your online bank, all it takes
> is a simple click or even less, as you can usually automate your bill
> payments. With online bill pay, it’s easy to manage your accounts from
> one central source and to track payments into and out of your
> account.@@ In spite of their many advantages, there are some drawbacks
> to using online banks as well. Here are some of the downsides/drawback
> of working with an online bank @@

Case:

if i specify word "one central source", it should extract para from starting n ending with delimiter '@@'

output:

> Online Bill Payment one of the great advantages of online banking is
> online bill pay. Rather than having to write checks or fill out forms
> to pay bills, once you set up your accounts at your online bank, all
> it takes is a simple click or even less, as you can usually automate
> your bill payments. With online bill pay, it’s easy to manage your
> accounts from one central source and to track payments into and out of
> your account.

```
 \bone central source\b(.*?)@@
```

https://regex101.com/r/IbZEkd/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tool is perl5 compatible, you can use:

```
@@\s*+\K(?:.(?!@@))*\bone central source\b.*?(?=@@)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, have the dot match a newline
- `@@\s*+\K` Match `@@`, match optional whitespace chars and then clear the match buff3er
- `(?:.(?!@@))*` Match any char when not directly followed by @@
- `\bone central source\b` Match literally between word boundaries to prevent partial word matches
- `.*?` Match any char, as least as possible
- `(?=@@)` Positive lookahead, assert @@ to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YqPlrA/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work: `/@@\s*((?:.(?!@@))*?\bone central source\b.*?)\s*@@/gs`

Testing it here: https://regex101.com/r/s9e1ej/1

The idea is to search for the `@@` possibly followed by spaces and then any char which isn't followed by `@@`. This can be done with a negative lookahead:

- `.(?!@@)` meaning anything not followed by `@@`.
- `(?:.(?!@@))*?` is this same pattern inside a non-capturing group which can be repeated but with the ungreedy option. This is to avoid eating your sentence.

As you can see in the example, the text can contain the `@` symbol like I did by adding an e-mail address in the text.

Then, as you did, search for the sentence you are looking for with the word boundary `\b`. I removed the case-insensitive flag so you might need to re-enable it if your sentence can be written in another case.

If you don't want to get the delimiting separator, you could put the middle part in a capturing group. And if you can't use a group with your tool then look at [*The fourth bird*'s nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72853334/653182) which is using the `\K` reset and a positive lookahead at the end.

Comment: thanks you for trying this, it works flawlessly :)